# ¿Cómo puedo descargar archivos sin usar librerías externas?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con Node.js, y mi programa lo que hace (principalmente) es un backstreaming de vídeos de YouTube (audioonly: true) a través del paquete `ytdl-core`.

Lo que quiero hacer ahora, es descargar el archivo de audio (si es posible, el aac de 128kbps) en una carpeta, con el nombre del título del vídeo. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
yt.getInfo(url, (err, info) => {
  if(err) return msg.channel.sendMessage('Invalid YouTube Link: ' + err);
  msg.guild.voiceConnection.playStream(yt(url, { audioonly: true }), { passes : 5 });
});
```

Este es el código, en el cual, `url` es el enlace del vídeo, `err` es el error que genera si hay algún problema al cargar el vídeo, e `info` es la información del vídeo (el cual, para [éste vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXRviuL6vMY), al pasarlo por un `console.log(info)`, devolvería todo [esto](http://pastebin.com/CcJ2dm38). Sí, estoy usando FFMPEG para esto.

En el caso de hacer `console.log(info.formats);`, recibiría [lo siguiente](http://pastebin.com/e94K4zmc), pero no sé muy bien cómo obtener la URL de un formato determinado.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías mejorar un poco tu lógica para ésto. La librería [ytdl-core](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core) es muy simple de manejar, además usa `streams` de Node.js, lo cual te permite subscribirte a algunos eventos como `end` para saber cuándo un vídeo ha sido descargado.

Primero, debes de verificar si el vídeo está disponible en un formatado dado. Ésto lo puedes hacer, como ya lo sabes, por medio de la función `getInfo`. Ésta función te retorna toda la metadata del vídeo, como el nombre, author, formatos y el timestamp; éste último útil para saber la fecha de subida del vídeo.

```
const getVideoInfo = (url, cb) => {
  ydtl.getInfo(videoURL, (err, info) => {
    if (!err) {
      const title = info.title;
      const formats = info.formats.map(f => f.type);
      cb({ title, formats });
    }
  });
};
```

La siguiente función comprueba si el vídeo está disponible en un formato específico. Si es así, pasa una bandera y el nombre real del formato. Si no, pasa solamente la bandera (false).

```
const checkFormatAvailability = (videoInfo, format, cb) => {
  let isAvailable = false;
  let formatName;

  videoInfo.formats.forEach(f => {
    if (f.split(';')[0].includes(format)) {
      isAvailable = true;
      formatName = f;
    }
  });
  cb(isAvailable, formatName);
};
```

Si el vídeo está disponible en el formato requerido, se procederá a la descarga. Si no, se puede mostrar un mensaje informando que el formato no coincide con los disponibles del vídeo.

**Ejemplo**

```
const ydtl = require('ytdl-core');
const prompt = require('prompt');
const fs = require('fs');


/**
 * Comprueba si el vídeo está disponible en un
 * formato dado antes de empezar a descargar.
 * 
 * @param {string} format - nombre simple del
 * formato (mp4, mp3, webm)
 */
const checkFormatAvailability = (videoInfo, format, cb) => {
  let isAvailable = false;
  let formatName;

  videoInfo.formats.forEach(f => {
    if (f.split(';')[0].includes(format)) {
      isAvailable = true;
      formatName = f;
    }
  });
  cb(isAvailable, formatName);
};

/**
 * Obtiene alguna información del video, como
 * el título y los formatos disponibles.
 */
const getVideoInfo = (url, cb) => {
  ydtl.getInfo(url, (err, info) => {
    if (!err) {
      const title = info.title;
      const formats = info.formats.map(f => f.type);
      cb({ title, formats });
    }
  });
};



prompt.start();
prompt.message = null; // elimina el "prompt:"

prompt.get({
  properties: {
    url: {
      description: 'Enter video URL'
    },
    format: {
      description: 'Enter download format'
    }
  }
}, (err, result) => {
  const { url, format } = result;
  start(url, format);
});


function start (videoURL, format) {
  let videoInfo = {};

  getVideoInfo(videoURL, data => {
    console.log('[+] Video metadata downloaded');
    videoInfo = data

    checkFormatAvailability(videoInfo, format, (isAvailable, formatName) => {
      if (isAvailable) {
        console.log(`Video available in format ${format}`);
        console.log('[+] Starting download...');
        ydtl(videoURL, { format: formatName })
          .on('end', () => console.log('Download complete'))
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./music/${videoInfo.title}.${format}`));
      } else {
        console.log("I'm sorry, the video is not available in this format");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

[image]

Comment: Sí, eso permite descargar el vídeo en el formato deseado, pero hay un problema, yo lo quería en audio solo. Aunque ya solucioné el problema y añadí un convertidor con FFMPEG (de webm a mp3). Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Genial. Por cierto, creo que ytdl tiene una opción llamada `filter` donde puedes asignarle true a la opción `audioonly` para obtener solo el audio.

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

let url = params[0];
if (url == '' || url == undefined) return msg.channel.sendMessage(`You must add a **YouTube** url.`).then(m => m.delete(10000));
if (!url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") && !url.startsWith("https://youtu.be/")) return msg.channel.sendMessage(`Invalid YouTube Link.`).then(m => m.delete(10000));
ytdl.getInfo(url, (err, info) => {
  if (err) return msg.channel.sendMessage('Invalid YouTube Link: ' + err);
  fs.access(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.mp3`, fs.constants.R_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
      msg.channel.sendMessage(`Found: ${info.title}`)
      let sender = params[1];
      if (sender === undefined) return;
      if (sender === 'ok') return msg.channel.sendFile(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.mp3`);
    }else{
      msg.channel.sendMessage(`Downloading: ${info.title}`);
      ytdl(url, {
        filter: function(format) {
          return format.type === 'audio/webm; codecs="vorbis"';
        }
      })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.webm`))
        .on('finish', function() {
          msg.channel.sendMessage("Download complete, transcoding...");
          ffmpeg(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.webm`).preset('mp3').save(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.mp3`)
            .on('end', function(stdout, stderr) {
              msg.channel.sendMessage("Transcoding succeeded!");
              fs.unlink(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.webm`, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                msg.channel.sendMessage(`The file **./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.webm** has been deleted.`);
              });
              let sender = params[1];
              if (sender === undefined) return;
              if (sender === 'ok') return msg.channel.sendFile(`./dmusic/${info.title.replace(/[^a-z ]/gi,"").replace(/[ ]{2}/g,"")}.mp3`);
            });
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Todo este código hace lo siguiente:

1. Revisa si el enlace es correcto.
2. Si lo es, revisa si existe en el directorio definido para la descarga.
3. Si está, envía un mensaje avisando de que el archivo está descargado.

   1. Si el segundo parámetro es 'ok', enviará el archivo.
4. Si no lo está, lo descargará.
5. Cuando la descarga se termina, FFMPEG lo convierte en un archivo MP3.
6. Una vez convertido, borra el archivo WEBM.

   1. Si el segundo parámetro es 'ok', enviará el archivo.